# PreUpdate not firing when adding to a collection

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I have a JPA annotated class which contains a collection like so:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private int id; 
    @Basic
    private String name;    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ORG", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="MINION"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="EMP"))
    private List<Employee> minions = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(){ ... }
}
```

What I'm seeing is that if I have a managed Employee entity and I add to it's collection of minions the `preUpdate` method is not getting invoked. A new row is added to the mapping table in the DB so I know the update is going through.  If I change a property directly on the Employee, like name, then `preUpdate` fires as expected when the transaction is committed.

Is there a way to get PreUpdate to fire when a mapped collection is modified? Or is there some other technique or Hibernate specific annotation for detecting when this happens?

Comment: use @Version - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17073342/178526

Answer (score 7):

`@PreUpdate` event is triggered just before [database UPDATE operation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/listeners.html#d0e1979) is executed for the entity in question.

If you're not updating direct properties of `Employee`, there's no `UPDATE` to execute for its table and thus `@PreUpdate` listener is never called. You should have better luck using `@PrePersist` event which is triggered by "flush" rather than "update".

Comment: You're correct. PrePersist doesn't help either since it is fired on INSERT and in this case the collection is modified after the entity has already been persisted.  I guess my question is really asking if there are techniques that function similar to PreUpdate to detect when a mapped collection is modified.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "fired on INSERT". Aren't you calling `entityManager.persist(employee)` to save your collection? If you're not (e.g. you're relying on flush _only_) you're going to have to configure your own listener for one (or more) of "flush" / "auto-flush" / "flush-entity" events (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html#d0e500). Or, for a Hibernate-specific  solution, write your own interceptor (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-interceptors) - onFlushDirty() is always called

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a this custom workaround works:

Create a subclass of ArrayList which identifies changes through ActionListener pattern

```
public class Employee {
    ....

    private List<Employee> minions = createChangeNotifierList();

    private List<Employee> createChangeNotifierList() {
        ChangeNotifierList<Employee> l = new ChangeNotifierList<Employee>();
        l.setActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                preUpdate();
            }
        });
        return l;
    }

    public void setMinions(List<Employee> l) {
        if (!(l instanceof ChangeNotifierList)) {
            l = createChangeNotifierList();
            preUpdate();
        }
        this.minions = l;
    }

    public void preUpdate(){ ... }
}


public class ChangeNotifierList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    private ActionListener actionListener;

    public ChangeNotifierList() {
    }

    public ChangeNotifierList(List<T> list) {
        super.addAll(list);
    }

    public void setActionListener(ActionListener actionListener) {
        this.actionListener = actionListener;
    }

    public boolean add(T e) {
        boolean b = super.add(e);
        if (b) {
            notifyChange();
        }
        return b;
}

    private void notifyChange() {
        actionListener.actionPerformed(null);
    }

    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation for Hibernate provider:

http://pastebin.com/8cPB96bZ

Generally you just mark methods that should be called in the case of a dirty collection with @PreCollectionChange annotation.

Comment: It's always a good idea to include the import statements, so in any case it's possible to determine which import is exactly needed. In this case, I have where you took the ReflectionUtils from. Nowdays, I think many third party libraries have a class caled `ReflectionUtils` included